# ListView clickable false not working

Tags: android, listview

I would like to make Android `ListView` non clickable for sometime, until my `AysncTask` finished.

So I Used

```
lv.setClickable(false);
```

But its not working. `ListView` still takes clicks. Need help.

Comment: I put this inside OnItemClick(...) function;

Comment: Set your ListView on `preExecute` method  `lv.setEnabled(false);` and in your `postExecute` re-enable it again `lv.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: I checked with lv.setClickable(false); When I used lv.setEnable(false), then The ListView still seems receiving action because it shows option for "Force Close" or "Wait". :(

Answer (score 5):

What has worked for me is setting two attributes in the XML for my list items. I set `clickable="false"` and `focusable="true"`. So each of my list items is inflating an XML file similar to this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <!-- Children here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure exactly why this works, although this is my guess:

- Using just the clickable attribute doesn't work because although the LinearLayout isn't clickable, the children inside it still are. Then the children get the click event but don't use it and forward it up to the LinearLayout.
- By making the LinearLayout focusable, it will now take the click event, and then drop it because it isn't clickable.

Hope this helps. If anyone knows for sure why this approach works, please chime in.

Comment: Nice hack dude. Unlike most of the other solutions presented all over SO, this one is elegant AND it actually WORKS. And I think I agree with your explanation about *how* it works, although I don't feel like  proving it out right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
    lv.setEnabled(false);
```

EDIT: ok sorry my fault.

I think the problem is that its not the ListView you are clicking but the View representing each item in your ListView. So try this:

```
View itemView = lv.findViewTraversal(id_of_your_view);
itemView.setClickable(false);
```

I hope this works.

Comment: If I used setEnabled(false); Its not taking any input. But continuously pressing menu prompt me for "Force Close" or "Wait". I just not want to take input for any click.

Answer (score 0):

1. did you try `setFocusable` / `setEnabled` methods ?
2. You can in your onItemClick method :

`if(!mWorking){
    mWorking = true;
    //do the job...
}`

1. You can try to implement a [SimpleOnGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and override the [onSingleTapConfirmed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method. There is a lot of tuts on google.

I hope this will help you

Comment: Your option 1 & 2 didn't work. When many press/touch happen on the listview it shows me option for "Force close" or "wait". I didn't try with Option 3. I'll check.